# Exporting specific Stata output from ivreg2 to LaTeX

Tags: latex, export, stata

I am trying to export results of the Sanderson-Windmeijer multivariate F test of excluded instruments from Stata. Consider the following working example:

```
use http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/mroz.dta, clear
ivreg2 lwage exper expersq (educ hours =age kidslt6 kidsge6), first
```

Among the output can be found

```
                                           (Underid)            (Weak id)
Variable     | F(  3,   422)  P-val | SW Chi-sq(  2) P-val | SW F(  2,   422)
educ         |       4.34    0.0050 |       13.17   0.0014 |        6.49
hours        |       6.44    0.0003 |       19.50   0.0001 |        9.61
```

and

```
                                                      Number of obs =      428
                                                      F(  4,   423) =     5.47
                                                      Prob > F      =   0.0003
Total (centered) SS     =  223.3274513                Centered R2   =   0.1151
Total (uncentered) SS   =   829.594813                Uncentered R2 =   0.7618
Residual SS             =  197.6266298                Root MSE      =    .6795

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       lwage | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        educ |   .1016889   .0836986     1.21   0.224    -.0623574    .2657351
       hours |   .0001501   .0002139     0.70   0.483    -.0002691    .0005692
       exper |   .0337614   .0186123     1.81   0.070     -.002718    .0702407
     expersq |   -.000703   .0004682    -1.50   0.133    -.0016206    .0002145
       _cons |  -.5677476   1.067838    -0.53   0.595    -2.660671    1.525176
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Underidentification test (Anderson canon. corr. LM statistic):          12.773
                                                   Chi-sq(2) P-val =    0.0017
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Weak identification test (Cragg-Donald Wald F statistic):                4.327
Stock-Yogo weak ID test critical values: 10% maximal IV size             13.43
                                         15% maximal IV size              8.18
                                         20% maximal IV size              6.40
                                         25% maximal IV size              5.45
Source: Stock-Yogo (2005).  Reproduced by permission.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sargan statistic (overidentification test of all instruments):           0.177
                                                   Chi-sq(1) P-val =    0.6738
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to output a table with two panels:

1. the top panel has the coefficients for `educ, hours, expert, expersq,` and `cons`
2. the bottom panel presents the `R^2`, and the `Sanderson-Windmeijer F test` for each regressor.

And I would like the code to be "scalable" so that if I were to run another regression, say,

```
ivreg2 lwage exper  (educ hours =age kidslt6 kidsge6), first
```

I can just append the estimates for this column.

I know `eststo` can help with this and I checked [this thread on Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1505843-ivreghdfe-cannot-show-first-stage-outcome), but when I run `ereturn list` I cannot find the required F-test for each variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sanderson-Windmeijer F test is in a stored matrix. It can be found if you run `mat list e(first)` after your regression:

```
. mat list e(first)

e(first)[21,2]
              educ      hours
   rmse  2.2586145  725.75198
sheapr2  .02984566  .04363689
    pr2  .02994351  .04377996
      F  4.3420709  6.4403383
     df          3          3
   df_r        422        422
 pvalue  .00498557  .00028482
    SWF  6.4910143  9.6119846
 SWFdf1          2          2
 SWFdf2        422        422
   SWFp  .00167294  .00008277
 SWchi2  13.166607  19.497296
SWchi2p  .00138327  .00005837
   SWr2  .02984498  .04356964
    APF  6.4602774  9.5821494
 APFdf1          2          2
 APFdf2        422        422
   APFp  .00172358  .00008516
 APchi2  13.104259  19.436777
APchi2p  .00142707  .00006017
   APr2  .02970785  .04344028
```

Here's a working example that would add these F-stats to the stored estimates and make a table containing them, using the two regressions you mentioned:

```
use http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/mroz.dta, clear
eststo: ivreg2 lwage exper expersq (educ hours =age kidslt6 kidsge6), first
estadd scalar f_test_educ =  e(first)[8,1]
estadd scalar f_test_hours =  e(first)[8,2]
eststo: ivreg2 lwage exper         (educ hours =age kidslt6 kidsge6), first
estadd scalar f_test_educ =  e(first)[8,1]
estadd scalar f_test_hours =  e(first)[8,2]

esttab , b(3) se(3) stats(f_test_educ f_test_hours r2, fmt(3 3 3))
```

Here's output of the `esttab` command:

```
--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
                    lwage           lwage   
--------------------------------------------
educ                0.102           0.107   
                  (0.084)         (0.084)   

hours               0.000           0.000   
                  (0.000)         (0.000)   

exper               0.034           0.010   
                  (0.019)         (0.007)   

expersq            -0.001                   
                  (0.000)                   

_cons              -0.568          -0.560   
                  (1.068)         (1.086)   
--------------------------------------------
f_test_educ         6.491           6.687   
f_test_hours        9.612          10.802   
r2                  0.115           0.082   
--------------------------------------------
Standard errors in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```